# Take list as input from user, and use it in other predicates like append, and some other which I want to implement a code

Tags: prolog

```
 test():-
    write("list1"),
    read(A),
    write("list2"),
    read(B),
    write(A),
    write(B).

 append([],X,X).
 append([X|Y],Z,[X|W]) :- append(Y,Z,W).'
```

The output of the code is:

```
?- test().
     list1[A,B,C].
     list2|: [D,E].
     [_3842,_3848,_3854][_3866,_3872]
     true.
```

But I want it to be as normal Alphabets.

Comment: You're reading terms, which means you're asking the user to enter Prolog on the terminal, which means when you write `[A,B,C].`, Prolog is interpreting that as a list of three uninstantiated variables. This is not an encoding problem, if you enter `[a,b,c].` or `['A','B','C'].` it will work as you expect. As @ValeraGrishin states below, if you want raw strings, you will have to use `read_string/3` but if you actually want Prolog terms, you will have to properly escape uppercase atoms.

Answer (score 2):

The `read` predicate is intended for reading terms. For reading strings, use `read_string` instead.